# How to invert the sense of each predicate in a std::vector<> of them?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, predicate

I have two vectors of predicates:

```
typedef std::function<bool(int)> pred;

vector<pred> v1;
vector<pred> v2;
```

I need to merge them into one, but the predicates from the second vector should be inverted (i.e. they should return `true` in the cases they normaly return `false`). So, in fact i need a kind of "inverting" wrapper.

I created an inversion function and a struct which holds an original predicate and inverts its value:

```
struct inverted
{
  pred pr;
  inverted(pred pr_) : pr(pr_) {}

  bool operator () (int i) {return !pr(i);}
};

pred CreateInverted(pred pr)
{
  return inverted(pr);
}
```

Using this, the inversion of the vector predicates might look like:

```
transform( v2.begin(), v2.end(), v2.begin(), CreateInverted );
```

But I'd like to know if there are better solutions, specially based on the Standard Library?

No C++11, Boost is allowed.

Comment: No, he does want to negate the truth of the predicates from `v2` if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Jack: exactly. ``truth`` to ``false`` and vice versa.

Comment: This is as standard as it gets, what more do you want? That's a tripple gold star implementation :) By the way, aren't you forgetting to pass the int param to the wrapped predicate?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: i thought there are might be some "not1"-like templates solutions or something. You're right, it seems i forgot. Now it's should be ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your predicate follows certain conventions, you can use `std::not1` to create the inverted predicate. Here is an example:

```
struct foobar : std::unary_function<bool, int>
{
    bool operator()(int value) const { return value > 42; }
};

do_something_if(values.begin(), values.end(), std::not1(foobar());
```

Answer (score 3):

The standard library has a `std::not1` predicate that takes a unary predicate and yields the negation of the argument, so there is no need to provide your own functor for this [code is not tested, you might need to correct the syntax]:

```
std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), 
                std::not1< std::function<bool(int)> > );
```

Comment: In this case i have to inherit my functors from ``std::unary_function``, am i right? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @fogbit: Not sure, you would have to test it. It depends on whether `std::not1` uses the typedefs that `std::unary_function` provides or not. Also, I seem to recall that there were specific rules for `std::function` that would provide equivalent typedefs in some cases, so that would also make it work. If you get to try it, I'd like to know the result :)

Comment: @fogbit as far as I can see, you do not have to inherit from `std::unary_function`, which has been deprecated in C++11 anyway. David's code sample works fine.

Comment: @juanchopanza: inspite of i don't use C++11, many thanks for this remark. I didn't knew that.

Comment: @fogbit but you are using `std::function`, which is C++11.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, @juanchopanza: std::tr1::function, i'm sorry to made you confused. But i mentioned about it in my message - ``No C11``.

Comment: @fogbit I edited your question to say "no C++11" instead of "no C11", since they are really quite different.

Comment: @fogbit: have you tested the code above? I am curious to know whether it would work in C++03 try.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: i got "error C2039: 'argument_type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::function<_Fty>'" in VS 2008

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a better way to solve your problem.

You actually use a `transformer` function together with the `stl::transform` which should be used exactly for your purpose.

This is considerable almost reference code!

Comment: Except that OP can bypass `inverted` and `CreateInverted` and just use `std::not1`.